# How to patch / configure a nodemcu build for SparkFun ESP32 Thing

Tags: esp32, nodemcu-build, sparkfun

I have been using nodemcu-build for 8266 modules with success for several projects.

I have been trying to replicate the same development environment using SparkFun ESP32 Thing using the beta version of nodemcu-build for ESP32.

After building, downloading a build it appears to successfully flash to the ESP32 Thing. But then
it displays the following error message:

```
rtc_clk_init: Possibly invalid CONFIG_ESP32_XTAL_FREQ setting (40MHz). Detected 26 MHz
```

From my research it appears that SparkFun build these modules with 26MHz xtals, yet the standard is for 40 MHz.  The error message suggests to me that the nodemcu-build for ESP32 assumes a 40MHz xtal.

Is there any way to patch to configure for the different frequency.  [I found a reverse situation where the problem was to patch a 26MHz generated binary to run at 40MHz.](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=8119)

But I'm unwilling to start patching without having confirmation as to exactly what is the correct process.

Comment: Still trying to sort out the problem.  Turns out if I connect at 74880 baud, I get readable output and able to interact with Lua.  74880 = 115200 * 26/40, i.e. scaled down in proportion to the difference in Xtal frequency.  Googling indicates that WiFi doesn't work in these circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to patch to configure for the different frequency.

Simple answer: no, not in the cloud builder.

Elaborate answer: yes, but you have to build the firmware yourself. The relevant configuration param is documented in the ESP-IDF Programming Guide at https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/api-reference/kconfig.html#config-esp32-xtal-freq-sel

> Main XTAL frequency
>
> Found in: Component config > ESP32-specific
>
> ESP32 currently supports the following XTAL frequencies:
>
> - 26 MHz
> - 40 MHz
>
> Startup code can automatically estimate XTAL frequency. This feature
>   uses the internal 8MHz oscillator as a reference. Because the internal
>   oscillator frequency is temperature dependent, it is not recommended
>   to use automatic XTAL frequency detection in applications which need
>   to work at high ambient temperatures and use high-temperature
>   qualified chips and modules.

Unless you plan to very frequently build firmware binaries I suggest you give my Docker build image a try: https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build/

Comment: SUCCESS! Eventually .... This was my first time using Docker, so it was a long slog.  Also had to carefully re-read your github README as well as the above Espressif documentation. THANK YOU!